# apply padding to only the first view in an adapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

I am trying to add some padding to a single view in an array adapter.

In the getView() method i could say:

```
if(position==0){
   rowView.setPadding(60,0,0,0);

}
```

but the position isn't always correct because the convertView is recycled.

Has anyone tried to do anything like this?

Comment: listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() will return the first visible position.

Comment: The position 0 will always be the first element of the list. Just make sure you add an else because you have to remove the padding on the other elements that share the same view.

Answer (score 1):

Position will always be `0` for the first item. However, you *will* need to set the padding back to normal for the other items:

```
if (position == 0) {
    rowView.setPadding(60, 0, 0, 0);
} else {
    rowView.setPadding(pad, pad, pad, pad);
}
```

Alternately, use multiple view types to return a different layout for the first item:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override 
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (position == 0) ? 0 : 1;
}

@Override
public View getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent, int position) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            // Inflate padded layout
        } else {
            // Inflate standard layout
        }
    }
}
```